# Meteor can't access array in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, meteor

HTML:

**index.html**

```
<head>
    <title>A Site</title>

</head>

<body>

</body>
```

**berkeley.html**

```
<template name="berkeley">
    <div class="container">
        <ul>    
            <!--nothing from the task template is displayed-->
            {{#each tasks}}
                {{> task}} 
            {{/each}} 
        </ul>

        <!--just testing without the template by accessing variable directly; still displays nothing-->
        <ul>
            {{#each tasks}}
                <li>{{fullName}}</li>
            {{/each}}
        </ul>
    </div>

</template>
```

JavaScript:

**logic.js**

```
Tasks = new Mongo.Collection("tasks");

if (Meteor.isClient) {
    Template.body.helpers({ 

        tasks: function() { 
            return Tasks.find({}, {sort: {createdAt: -1}}); 
        }

    });
}
```

I'm using Iron Router to render the Berkeley template when URL is '/berkeley'.

The HTML seems unable to get the array `tasks`, which exists in the JavaScript and is populated.

The `task` template is valid because if I exclude `{{#each tasks}}` and `{{/each}}` Meteor is able to display the static content in the `task` template, but when included, nothing is displayed.

Here is it on Meteorpad: http://meteorpad.com/pad/HLWuxo3wMc54dQP33/Copy%20of%20Leaderboard
(the entire body block doesn't display, in this case; I'm very confused)

Comment: do you have a template called body? Please share some more of your code, especially the HTML.

Comment: is your template name="body"  ? if its <template name="body"> should works fine?

Comment: Do you have data in your database?

Comment: I'm using Iron Router so I don't have a <template name="body">, but I believe Meteor inserts all templates within the body tags, so Template.body.helpers() should work, right?